# Host another application in my application

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to launch another app from my activity within a certain part of the activity layout so that my application is visible in background. Is it possible?
I know how to launch another application but just want to show it within certain part of my activity.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  The reason this is not possible is fundamental to Android: it sandboxes applications so that no other app can get control over your process address space.  The security implications of making this possible would be vast, and make your app susceptible to attack from another app if done incorrectly.  This could be theoretically possible with changes to the Android firmware, but out of the box, it's not possible.  (So, there is a way to do this "right," but you can't on most Android systems.)  It's always possible, if you've written both apps, to establish some IPC between them, and then control the UI that way, similar to how a service would talk to an Activity in your app.

I remember someone asking about this with respect to a "stumbleupon" like service for Android in the android-developers google group: the answer was the same: it might be nice, but ultimately the way the system is designed, it's not currently possible.

Edit: here's the link to the thread I mentioned:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/201a443b6758bd79/1cf2eaf728eca4af?lnk=gst&q=stumbleupon#1cf2eaf728eca4af